# Get category Display Mode

Tags: category

How can I programmatically get the Category "Display Mode" if it have a "Products only", "Static block only" or "Static block and products" ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$cateoryId = 16;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->load($categoryId);

$displayMode = $category->getDisplayMode();
//do something with $displayMode
```

Comment: Works here too. Only note that `$category->getDisplayMode()` mostly returns an empty string when the value was never explicitly modified. I only get "PAGE" for the few categories where I have set that.

Comment: if the display mode is static block, how can we get the id of the static cms block from the current category? (M2)